# AppWidgetProvider, how to determine the AppWidgetProvider for a specific widget

Tags: android, appwidgetprovider

I need a way to determine which AppWidgetProvider is active for the current
widget in the configure Activity. My current solution results in a NullException
on some devices, the appWidgetInfo.provider is null somehow.

Is there a better way to determine which AppWidgetProvider is corresponding to
a specific appWidgetId.

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(widgetId);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(
    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
             widgetId);
intent.setAction(RemoteWidgetViewsFactory.KEY_WIDGET_SETTING_REFRESH);

String appWidgetProviderName = appWidgetInfo.provider.getClassName();
if(appWidgetProviderName.equals(WidgetProvider.class.getName())) {
    intent.setClass(context, WidgetProvider.class);
}
else if(appWidgetProviderName.equals(WidgetProviderLarge.class.getName())) {
    intent.setClass(context, WidgetProviderLarge.class);
}

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem cause I also needed to determine the actual AppWidgetProvider class. Your question did help me and I probably can help you.
Just implement a method like this and you dont have to write code for each AppProvider class:

```
    private static Class<?> getAppWidgetProviderClass(Context context, int appWidgetId){
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    String appWidgetProviderName = appWidgetInfo.provider.getClassName();
    Class<?> myProvider = null;
    try {
        myProvider = Class.forName(appWidgetProviderName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf){
        Log.e("myProviderClass","Class:" + appWidgetProviderName + " not found!");
    }
    return myProvider;
}
```

after use it for the class definition Intent:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, getAppWidgetProviderClass(context, appWidgetId));
```

Hope it helps you!